# Laravel - I know my ViewModel, so can i pass that ViewModel through into the controller parameters?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a ViewModel and a controller method:

```
class TimesheetViewModel
{
    public /* TimesheetTotals */ $TimesheetTotals;
    public /* TimesheetEntry[] */ $Timesheets = array();   
    public /* int */ $AmountOfTimesheetEntries = 1;
}

...
public /* void */ function GetCreate()
{
    ...
    $timesheetViewModel = new TimesheetViewModel();
    ...            

    $timesheetViewModel->TimesheetTotals = $timesheetLogic->ColumnSum( $timesheetEntries );
    $timesheetViewModel->AmountOfTimesheetEntries = count( $timesheetEntries );
    $timesheetViewModel->Timesheets = $timesheetEntries;
    return View::make( 'Timesheet/Create', array( "Model" => $timesheetViewModel ) );
}
...
```

I have a form in my view that has a perfect replication of the properties in my view model...
Is there a way to have something like this in my controller :

```
...
public /* void */ function PostCreate( TimesheetViewModel $timesheetViewModel )
{
    // This will help because I do not have to do Input::all
    // and then map it (Or not map it at all and stick with 
    // an array that could change when someone is working on 
    // the form fields mucking things up) ?
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at form model binding: http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding

Since your form has a perfect replication of the properties in your model, you would be able to do something like this in your controller:

```
public function update($id)
{
    $timesheetViewModel = TimeSheetViewModel::find($id);

    if (!$timesheetViewModel->update(Input::all())) {
        return Redirect::back()
                ->with('message', 'Your time sheet was unable to be saved')
                ->withInput();
    }

    return Redirect::route('timesheet.success')
                ->with('message', 'Your timesheet was updated.');
}
```

Just something to note: you'll be required to open the form using the following Blade command:

```
{{ Form::model($timeSheetViewModel, array('route' => array('timeSheetViewModel.update', $timeSheetViewModel->id))) }}
```

The $timeSheetViewModel is just any time sheet view model that you'll be passing in, in order to update.